# Convert character "ß" (capital Eszett character) to "SS" for IE

Tags: css, unicode, character

Modern browsers like firefox, chrome etc. convert "ß" (Eszett character) to "SS" in uppercase using text-transform:uppercase but IE doesn't support this.Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If a browser has implemented `text-transform: uppercase` in a particular way, there is nothing you can do about it in CSS.

The effect is vaguely defined in CSS 2.1. In particular, it does not say how “ß” should be handled. CSS3 Text (Working Draft, hence work in progress) says that default case mapping as defined in Unicode be used. They specify that “ß” is mapped to “SS”. But IE does not do so; until version 7, it leaves “ß” intact in uppercasing, and from version 8, it maps it to “ẞ” U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S (which is a different mapping, now used to some extent in Germany).

So, CSS cannot fix this. It is generally best to do case mappings server-side or in authoring program. That is, if you want to display “STRASSE”, write “STRASSE” instead of writing “Straße” and trying to uppercase it with CSS. (Situations where you really want to display the same data either as-is or as uppercased are actually rather rare. So there’s not much point in the idea of having normal mixed-case text as content and uppercasing it only in rendering.)

If this is impossible for some reason (e.g., the data comes dynamically from an external resource with Ajax), you can use simple JavaScript to perform the replacement in the data itself.